# How to sort cells based on specific order of words, that match a word contained within the cell

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, indexing

I need to sort cells based on a specific word order, with the text inside the cell **containing** the specific word, and not just the word by itself. The cells update constantly and would need a(n) limitless/expanding range.

SORT, and MATCH in Google Sheets work fine for cells exactly matching words in order, with an example formula  being

=SORT(O2:O5,MATCH(O2:O5,{"A", "B", "C"},0),TRUE)

with the outcome being:

[Usage of Sort to match exact words](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1Bpa.png)

However, for some reason differs to excel when using the wildcard syntax of

```
"*[word]*"
```

In where the formula just completely bricks, shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLvhg.png)

## My expectations

Were to use the wildcard syntax in conjunction with the formula to order cells as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOmGc.png)

EDIT: [Alternate word order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsZJk.png) to push that you cant execute this with a regular sort

Comment: The QUERY in your formula is not doing anything by the way.

Comment: Just checked, you're right. I borrowed the formula from another post in Stackoverflow, since I don't know much about excel/sheet functions. I don't really know how to sort based on contained words, if you have any ideas It'd be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My expectations
> Were to use the wildcard syntax in conjunction with the formula to order cells as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOmGc.png)

It seems to like you just want to do a regular SORT

```
=SORT(02:O5)
```

### Update

```
=LET(range,O2:O5,
     order,{"Melon","Banana","Apple"},
     i,SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS(order)),
     SORT(range,TOCOL(IF(REGEXMATCH(range,order),i,),1),1,1,1))
```

### Update 2

```
=LET(range,FILTER(A4:A,A4:A<>""),
     order,{"Melon","Banana","Apple"},
     i,SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS(order)),
     SORT(range,TOCOL(IF(REGEXMATCH(range,"(?i)"&order),i,),1),1,1,1))
```

Comment: The examples of "A,B,C" were just for convenience, I need to sort based on a specific set of words, say {"*BANANA*", "*MELON*", "*APPLE*"}

it would sort

MELON - HONEY DEW
APPLE 2 - GREEN
BANANA - CAVENDISH
APPLE 1 - FUJI

to --->

BANANA - CAVENDISH
MELON - HONEY DEW
APPLE 1 - FUJI
APPLE 2 - GREEN

Comment: This works! However only for a specific range. The data is constantly updating, thus I need it to work on a limitless range. What formula/function would be useful for that / how would the formula look like given said situation?

Comment: The answer to this depends on several factors. Could you share a realistic-looking sample sheet? You can [Make an anonymous sample document](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScf4e8rJpjbDx-SQOH2c2xIaUP-ewnNJoqv9uRAXIrenUvZ_Q/viewform)

Comment: The text in the cells are extracted from a different file with constantly added data, so it wouldn't be to easy to transfer over a single document, however I did create an [anonymous sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Wtft3_891GWUB0OviVHA-iPUdL-hnJEAvxN-MAOFkYI/edit?usp=sharing) to illustrate the desired outcome with notes.

Comment: Update: I tried this with a much larger order of words, and for some reason certain words that appear in the list trigger an error in the formula, with the message: Error: FILTER has mismatched range sizes. Expected row count: 16. column count: 1. Actual row count: 23, column count: 1. Mind you, every word matches what's in the order, but for some reason this happens, what do?